# Using retrofit with google cloud endpoints

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints, retrofit

I have built a backend REST Server using google cloud endpoints.  How do I use retrofit to make calls to this REST API from my android client?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you searched for a solution online before asking the question?

Comment: This question doesn't deserve to have -4 votes. Like it or not, the answering of this question would do a lot of help for a lot of people.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Google cloud api URL as the base URL and proceed with the normal setup of retrofit. I don't think it is a big deal. Here is a link to a tutorial that could help u get started with retrofit. [Tutoral Link](http://blog.robinchutaux.com/blog/a-smart-way-to-use-retrofit/)

Comment: I'm trying to use this aproach, but it seams not to work. When I make a GET call to `https://storage.googleapis.com/[bucket]/path` using the public URL, the response is 401 error