# App Engine endpoint with Retrofit

Tags: android, google-app-engine, retrofit

Would like to use Retrofit for handling network requests between  Android Client and GAE endpoints.
GAE endpoints give Client/Server endpoint libraries to handle all the networking and also Oauth2 authentication which is nice. 
Retrofit helps well for asynchronous call, cancellation, parallel calls...so is better than android client asynctask.
 So can this Retrofit lib be configured with Appengine GAE endpoints or need to go through normal GAE servlet?

---

Just to clarify my question and make answers clear  for any who read this :

I had for my App :

Client side : cloud endpoint library generated by google plug in for eclipse

Back end side GAE : different API with methods coded in JPA such as :

```
@ApiMethod(name = "insertMyShareItem") 
public ShareItemData insertMyShareItemData(ShareItemData shareitemdata) {
    logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "insertMyShareItem"); 
}
```

Advantages of google cloud endpoint was endpoint libray , easy use of Auth2 and  automatically use of secure connections via HTTPS

Now I want to give up Async task in order to implement Retrofit or Volley. I understood I cannot use google cloud endpoint anymore and need to transform my methods on GAE Back end side in methods which extends HttpServlet  so I can access them by URL call with normal setup of Retrofit.

Which means now I need to care :

- how I pass my object to Retrofit and how I retrieve them on back end
- how I transform Retrofit HTTP call in a HTTPS call for secure connection
- how I implement and manage Auth2 and tokens between Client and GAE back end to establish secure authentication.

This is what I understood from search and below answers.Thks

Comment: I haven't used it with GAE Endpoints, but I think Retrofit can cope with it.

Comment: Hey @mg3, did you able to implement retrofit to work with gae endpoints? I ams struggling with same scenario.

Comment: Hi, @nsgulliver...I started using volley with calling servlet instead of endpoint and I could say I get used to it and liked it cause I feel GAE endpoint are too restrictive. Sorry for no deep answer

Answer (score 0):

Use the Google Cloud API URL as the base URL and proceed with the normal setup of Retrofit. I don't think it is a big deal. Here is [a link](http://blog.robinchutaux.com/blog/a-smart-way-to-use-retrofit/) to a tutorial that could help you get started with Retrofit.

<sup>[[source]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29605691/1429387)</sup>

Comment: Ok thanks. It means I cannot use a backend with endpoints and its automated generated library from the client side (which come with easy Oauth2 configuration and SSL already implemented). I need to put servet (get, post..) on backend and configure my Retrofit library with that. This is what I understood from my search and from your answer.Am I right?

Comment: @mg3, do you create your App Engine Endpoints module in Android Studio?

Comment: I created in Eclipse...currently  I am using the library+API automated endpoind of GAE but also some call to servlet of GAE....finally I found retrofit or volley would be good in some case but need to re implement Auth2 and SSL encryption (which come out of the box with GAE endpoint)...does my explanation not clear?

Comment: @mg3 I think if you have API named "myApi" and API method named "sayHi", the full endpoint name will be "protocol:host:port/myApi/sayHi". For example: `http://localhost:8080/myApi/sayHi`.

Comment: From client side: 
`@GET("/myApi/sayHi")
String sayHi();`

Comment: Indeed the way you described is our I do when using Retrofit and HTTP servlet method on GAE back end. I was just hoping there was a way to couple Retrofit with GAE endpoint (JPA or JDO) in order to integrate Retrofit easily with Google cloud endpoint library on my client side. Thks